# How to update a table only if the values passed are not undefined? [PostgreSQL]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to make some update request in PostgreSQL using javascript, but I'm having some trouble with the update method :

What I used to have was this :

```
var query = client.query("UPDATE COMPANY SET company_name=$1, phone=$2 WHERE company_id = $3", [data.company_name, data.phone, company_id_requested]);
```

This would update the table company no matter the value of `data.company_name` or `data.phone`. The thing is that these values can be undefined, but I don't want to update the tables value to NULL if these values are undefined.

I've tried a new code to solve this problem, but I really don't find it clean, especially since I have to do it for each update method...

```
    var queryText = "UPDATE COMPANY SET ";
    var params = [];
    if (data.company_name !== undefined) {
        if (params.length != 0)
            queryText += ", ";
        params.push(data.company_name);
        queryText += "company_name=$" + params.length;  
    }
    if (data.phone !== undefined) {
        if (params.length != 0)
            queryText += ", ";
        params.push(data.phone);
        queryText += "phone=$" + params.length;
    }
    params.push(company_id_requested);
    queryText += " WHERE company_id = $" + params.length;
    console.log(queryText);
    var query = client.query(queryText, params);
```

Here I pretty much construct the query. Isn't there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can't do it with `node-postgres`, because it doesn't allow dynamic use of column names in your query, much less custom types. But if you were to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), that would be fairly easy to accomplish.

Comment: On a second thought, I have published a possible solution for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will generate such an update for you, from a table name and an object with properties to be set:

```
function createUpdate(table, data) {
    if (!table || typeof table !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError("Parameter 'table' must be a non-empty string.");
    }
    if (!data || typeof data !== 'object') {
        throw new TypeError("Parameter 'data' must be an object.");
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(data)
        .filter(function (k) {
            return data[k] !== undefined;
        });
    var names = keys.map(function (k, index) {
        return k + ' = $' + (index + 1);
    }).join(', ');
    var values = keys.map(function (k) {
        return data[k];
    });
    return {
        query: 'UPDATE ' + table + ' SET ' + names,
        values: values
    };
}
```

**Testing:**

```
var obj = {
    one: 1,
    two: 'two',
    last: undefined
};

var update = createUpdate("Company", obj);
```

This creates object:

```
{ query: 'UPDATE Company SET one = $1, two = $2', values: [ 1, 'two' ] }
```

So you can call:

```
client.query(update.query, update.values);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the condition into the where clause:

```
var query = client.query("UPDATE COMPANY SET company_name=$1, phone=$2 WHERE company_id = $3 AND $1 IS NOT NULL AND $2 IS NOT NULL", [data.company_name, data.phone, company_id_requested]);
```

Comment: This produces a completely different update logic from the one inquired.